# How to use node.js code inside php file/script

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, bitcoin

I am very new in `node.js`, I am creating a bitcoin application in `php` and I need to use `Bitgo API` for creating wallet address and bitcoin transfer.

Bitgo have there API in node.js only. Please help me to call node.js API inside my php code.

Here is the API listed.

https://www.bitgo.com/api/?javascript#create-address

On user signup I need to execute the `Bitgo API` for creating addresses inside wallet. Bitgo returns the wallet address in response and I have to store in my database.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Bitgo have there API in node.js only" is wrong. They have a universal API that you can use with whatever technology you like. But they *also* offer an API wrapper written JavaScript.

Comment: On their documentation : `BitGo provides a simple and robust REST-ful API as well as a simple client javascript SDK to integrate multi-signature technology into your existing bitcoin applications and services.`

Comment: Don;t get confuse through `npm` you can implement client side javascript SDK `https://github.com/BitGo/BitGoJS`, its not required nodejs

Comment: @str can u please mention some API here which are not in node js,because i couldn't find any

Comment: @MohdSayeed but that API also need node js to run,i used that API,it is woking with node.js only

Answer (score 1):

The BitGo Express REST API is a lightweight service for developers that want to take advantage of BitGo but are developing in a language without a native BitGo SDK.

BitGo Express runs as a service in your own datacenter, and handles the client-side operations involving your own keys, such as partially signing transactions before submitting them to BitGo. This ensures your keys never leave your network, and are never seen by BitGo. BitGo Express can also proxy the standard BitGo REST APIs, providing a unified interface to BitGo through a single REST API.

To use BitGo Express:

Install BitGoJS
Run the following command in the bin directory:
./bitgo-express --debug --port 3080 --env test --bind localhost

Make all BitGo REST API calls to the machine on which bitgo-express is running.